# Ajax success if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When the user clicks on a remove button, the code sends a request to the server to remove that user from the DB first and then from the table list on the screen.

My problem is that a if else statment withint the ajax success does return what I want.

I can't add this code to fiddlers because it's linking to a database which is not accessible online.

```js
$(nTd).children('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    if(that.hasClass('icon-i-remove')){
       $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('href'),
          type: $(this).attr('method'),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            //PROBLEM HERE **********
            if(data.success == 'true' ){
               alert('true');
            } else {
               alert('false')
            };
       ;}
   });
```

So, 2 major problems.
The if statement doesn't run correctly. even if it return true, the server jumps to the else without caring about it.

The second issue is this.
When the user clicks on the remove button, the code should first check if the user has been deleted on the DB. If I have the ok from the DB, then I can remove the row from the table list without refreshing the page, otherwise I should display an error message (false return)

In my case, when I click remove, the code send a request to the server and doesn't care what the result is.

I need the code to wait before executing the client side remove. I need to know if that user has been removed from the db or not. 
I find it difficult to manage the if statement do. It seems it's not looking at the result back from the backend.

True or false it skips through either way. What's going wrong?

Comment: Dude, try to format your code. Look around and see how people do it...

Comment: please post server side code where you are returning a json object with property "success" as "true".

Comment: 2 things: 1) *Make sure your PHP uses `echo` to return a string you interpret on the JavaScript side* **example** `echo("true"); // where "true" is the returned STRING` 2) *Try using [**this jQuery Plugin**](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js), it will make ajax calls 100x easier.* **example** [**see here**](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it actually returning `'true'`? Or is it returning `true`? Two different things

**UPDATE**

```js
$(nTd).children('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    if(that.hasClass('icon-i-remove')){
       $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('href'),
          type: $(this).attr('method'),
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            //PROBLEM HERE **********
            if(data.success == true ){   <-- Change to true (remove quotes)
               alert('true');
            } else {
               alert('false')
            };
       ;}
   });
```

Comment: If you arent familiar with it, learn about variable types. You are trying to check if a possible `boolean` variable is a `string`

Comment: HI Barry, Thanks for answering. it isn't a boolean true or false, but a json return 'success' : 'true'  or 'success' : 'false'

Comment: Did you look to see what the contents of `data.success` were?

Comment: yes, and if I console.log(data.success) I get the result. But the if statement doesn't seem to work correctly. Even if data.success returns true, if statement doesn't care to execute the alert('true'), but it goes straight to the alert('false'). It seems that it doesn't care what the return from the json is. Also, I was wondering, since I'm using an if statement within ajax success, obviusly it will always return successful and run what withint the success function. I have read the jquery docs and looked around but I can't find a reason why it doesn't execute correctly the if else statement.

Comment: Found the issue. The backend developer wrote some of json like this: 'success' : 'true'  and some others 'success' : true .... quotes I didn't see. Thanks Barry for your hepl

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax success callback is executing.. it means the server side operation was completed SUCCESFULLY.

If not, then the server should not send back a 200 that will get interpreted as a success

Comment: He is returning JSON. The contents of that data structure is what he is checking, its not an ajax success/fail